# Rails Error: joins + include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have the following models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :images
 has_one :preference
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :person
end

class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :person
end
```

I am trying to fetch all images that are public and at the same time eager load the people who own those images:

```
    Image.find(:all, :conditions =>  ["images.person_id = ? AND preferences.image_privacy = ?", user.id, PRIVACY_PUBLIC],
               :joins => [:person => :user_preference], :include => :person)
```

It appears Rails does not like the :include (I believe because :person is referenced in 2 models).  This is the error I get (which disappears when I drop the :include option):

"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Not unique table/alias: 'people'"

I can get around this by writing out the actual JOIN command as a string and passing it into the :include option, but this not Rails-y so I was hoping there's a cleaner way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the sql query here, You should be able to see that in the log

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you call it "preferences", and not user_preferences. So you join should be:

```
:joins => [:person => :preference])
```

Answer (score 0):

By using JOIN you are actively including the People table, so you shoudn't need to add "include" again. This should work:

```
  Image.find(:all, :conditions =>  ["images.person_id = ? AND preferences.image_privacy = ?", user.id, PRIVACY_PUBLIC],
           :joins => [:person => :user_preference])
```

Comment: that's is not correct, since joins does not do eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue with Table Aliasing, rails doc has great details in [Table Aliasing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

also, post SQL here will be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote :conditions => ["images.person_id", user.id] and you said that you want to load images and **people** who owns those images. But it looks like you are loading images that belongs to one person (not to group of people), because you specify only one user.id.

I would do it this way:

```
Person.find(user.id, :include => [:images, :preference], :conditions => ["preferences.image_privacy = ?", PRIVACY_PUBLIC])
```

It will load person and his/her images.

Probably I don't understand your problem correctly, because what I think you want to do doesn't seem logic to me.

Instead of using conditions you can try [named_scope](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope)